# .setdefault with list filled by function

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

How do I use .setdefault with the default being a list that i filled in a function? For example,

```
import random
foundwords = []

with open("text", "r") as file:
    contents = file.read().replace('\n',' ')
words = contents.split(' ')

def findwords(word):
    for i in range(len(words) - 1):
        if words[i] == word:
            if not words[i + 1] == '':
                foundwords.append(words[i + 1])

wordsDict = {}
for i in range(len(words) - 1):
    findwords(words[i])
    wordsDict.setdefault(words[i], foundwords)
    del foundwords[:]

def assemble():
    start = words[random.randint(0, len(words))]
    print(start.capitalize())



assemble()
```

When I check wordsDict, all lists are empty. However, I know that the lists *are* filled.

Comment: What does the `assemble()` function have to do with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're not making a copy of the `foundwords` list when you use `.setdefault()`, so all the dictionary elements refer to the same list. Then you remove all the elements of that list with `del foundwords[:]`, so they all refer to that empty list.

Make a copy of the list when you add it to the dictionary.

```
for word in words:
    findwords(word)
    wordsDict.setdefault(word, foundwords[:])
    del foundwords[:]
```

Better would be to change `findwords()` so it returns a new list instead of writing into a global variable.

```
def findwords(word):
    foundwords = []
    for i in range(len(words) - 1):
        if words[i] == word:
            if not words[i + 1] == '':
                foundwords.append(words[i + 1])
    return foundwords

for words in words:
    wordsDict.setdefault(word, findwords(word))
```

Comment: IMHO both ways are not optimal, as the function is called or the list is copied even if the value _is_ in the dict. Better not use `setdefault` but a simple `if` instead.